# Improving performance of a Python function that outputs the pixels that are different between two images

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm working on a computer vision project and am looking to build a fast function that compares two images and outputs only the pixels where the differences between the pixels of the two images are sufficiently different. Other pixels get set to (0,0,0). In practice, I want the camera to detect objects and ignore the background.

My issue is the function doesn't run fast enough. What are some ways to speed things up?

```
def get_diff_image(fixed_image): 
    #get new image
    new_image = current_image()

    #get diff
    diff = abs(fixed_image-new_image)

    #creating a filter array 
    filter_array = np.empty(shape = (fixed_image.shape[0], fixed_image.shape[1]))
    for idx, row in enumerate(diff):
        for idx2, pixel in enumerate(row):
            mag = np.linalg.norm(pixel)
            if mag > 40:
                filter_array[idx][idx2] = True
            else:
                filter_array[idx][idx2] = False

    #applying filter
    filter_image = np.copy(new_image)
    filter_image[filter_array == False] = [0, 0, 0]
    return filter_image
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, your biggest slow down in this code is iterating over every pixel in Python. Since Python is an interpreted language, these iterations take much longer than their equivalents in C/C++, which numpy uses under the hood.

Conveniently, you can specify an axis for `numpy.linalg.norm`, so you can get all the magnitudes in one numpy command. In this case, your pixels are on axis 2, so we'll take the norm on that axis, like this:

```
mags = np.linalg.norm(diff, axis=2)
```

Here, `mags` will have the same shape as `filter_array`, and each location will hold the magnitude of the corresponding pixel.

Using a boolean operator on a numpy array returns an array of bools, so:

```
filter_array = mags > 40
```

With the loops removed, the whole thing looks like this:

```
def get_diff_image(fixed_image): 
    #get new image
    new_image = current_image()

    #get diff
    diff = abs(fixed_image-new_image)

    #creating a filter array 
    mags = np.linalg.norm(diff, axis=2)
    filter_array = mags > 40

    #applying filter
    filter_image = np.copy(new_image)
    filter_image[filter_array == False] = [0, 0, 0]
    return filter_image
```

But there is still more efficiency to be gained.

As noted by pete2fiddy, the magnitude of a vector doesn't depend on its direction. The absolute value operator only changes direction, not magnitude, so we just don't need it here. Sweet!

The biggest remaining performance gain is to avoid copying the image. If you need to preserve the original image, start by allocating zeros for the output array since zeroing memory is often hardware accelerated. Then, copy only the required pixels. If you don't need the original and only plan to use the filtered one, then modifying the image in-place will give much better performance.

Here's an updated function with those changes in place:

```
def get_diff_image(fixed_image): 
    #get new image
    new_image = current_image()

    # Compute difference magnitudes
    mags = np.linalg.norm(fixed_image - new_image, axis=2)

    # Preserve original image
    filter_image = np.zeros_like(new_image)
    filter_image[mag > 40] = new_image[mag > 40]
    return filter_image

    # Avoid copy entirely (overwrites original!)
    # new_image[mag < 40] = [0, 0, 0]
    # return new_image
```

Comment: incredibly useful, ty

Answer (score 0):

The slow part is your loop.

```
    for idx, row in enumerate(diff):
        for idx2, pixel in enumerate(row):
            mag = np.linalg.norm(pixel)
            if mag > 40:
                filter_array[idx][idx2] = True
            else:
                filter_array[idx][idx2] = False
```

Doing this in Python code is much slower than doing this in numpy's [implicit loop over an array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html).  I believe that this would apply to the norm call in which case you would have `mag = np.linalg.norm(diff)` which would create the array `mag`.   You could the use [numpy's greater function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.greater.html#numpy.greater) applied to the whole array to get filter_array.

The loop over the array will then be done in numpy's C code which is an order of magnitude faster (in general).

Answer (score 0):

Nested loops in python run very slowly. However, this can often be mitigated through letting numpy which is largely written in C. Try giving this a go:

def get_image_difference_magnitudes(image1, image2):

```
'''order of subtraction does not matter, because the magnitude
of any vector is always a positive scalar'''

image_subtractions = image1-image2

'''checks if the image has channels or not, i.e.
if the two images are grayscaled or not. Calculating the magnitude
of change differs for both cases'''

if len(image1.shape) == 2:
    return np.abs(image_subtractions)

'''returns the magnitude of change for each pixel. The "axis = 2"
part of np.linalg.norm specifies that, rather than the output that
does not specify the axis, it will return an image that replaces each
pixel, which contains a vector of the difference between the two images,
with the magnitude of the vector at that pixel'''

return np.linalg.norm(image_subtractions, axis = 2)
```

def difference_magnitude_threshold_images(image1, image2, threshold):
    image_subtraction_magnitudes = get_image_difference_magnitudes(image1, image2)

```
'''creates a numpy array of "False" that is the same shape as the
width and height of the image. Slicing the shape to 2 makes it so
that the mask is only width x height, and not width x height x 3,
in the case of RGB'''

threshold_mask = np.zeros(image1.shape[:2], dtype = np.bool)

'''checks each element of image_subtraction_magnitudes, and for
all instances where the magnitude of difference at that pixel is
greater than threshold, set the mask = to True'''

threshold_mask[image_subtraction_magnitudes > threshold] = True
return threshold_mask
```

The above also has the benefit of being only a few lines long (were you to fit it into one function). The way you apply the filter looks fine to me -- I'm not sure if there is a faster way to do it. Also, I apologize for the formatting. I wasn't sure how to indent within a code block, so I left the function names outside of the code block.